# for in range() inside tkinter

Tags: loops, for-loop, tkinter

I can't run this code properly, I want to read the label for each 0.5 second but its free then show the results all at once even if I changed the time sleep to 1 its going to take like 5 second to show. in other way its work on the loop in the background then show the results at the end

```py
from tkinter import *
import time

win=Tk()

for t in range (5,0,-1):

    Mn = t % 60

    Hr = t // 60

    if int(Hr)<10 and int(Mn)<10:
        xmn = str(Mn).zfill(2)
        xhr=str(Hr).zfill(2)
        label=Label(win,text=(xhr+':'+xmn, 'Hr<10'))
        label.pack()
        #print(xhr+':'+xmn, 'Hr<10')
    else:
        label = Label(win, text=(str(Hr).zfill(2)+':'+str(Mn)))
        label.pack()
        #print(str(Hr).zfill(2)+':'+str(Mn), 'else')


    time.sleep(0.5)
    
label=Label(win,text='')
label.pack()
win.geometry('400x400')
win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear about what you are trying, but I can give a few pointers:

The `time.sleep()` function will suspend the application including GUI updates, which is why the window displays only after the loop is run. You can force the application to process the queue with `update()`. You might want to research the `after()` function which is normally used for periodic updates.

```py
from tkinter import *
import time

win = Tk()
win.geometry('400x400')

for t in range(5,0,-1):
    Mn = t % 60
    Hr = t // 60

    if int(Hr)<10 and int(Mn)<10:
        xmn = str(Mn).zfill(2)
        xhr = str(Hr).zfill(2)
        label = Label(win, text=(xhr+':'+xmn, 'Hr<10'))
        label.pack()
    else:
        label = Label(win, text=(str(Hr).zfill(2)+':'+str(Mn)))
        label.pack()

    time.sleep(0.5)
    win.update()    # Force window to update

win.mainloop()
```

Does this example produce the effect you are after?

**Addition**

You can use `after()` to schedule a function to run after a time. Example below:

```
from tkinter import *
import time

win = Tk()
win.geometry('400x400')
display = Label(win)
display.pack(pady=10)

def display_number(n):
    display.configure(text=str(n))      # Configure label to show number
    win.after(500, display_number, n+1) # Schedule function to run after
                                        # 500 milliseconds with argument n+1

display_number(0)   # Calls function first time with argument 0

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: @Cool Cloud, thank you!
your code works 100%
can you tell me how I can use (after) please?

Comment: Added example of after() to my answer

Comment: @Cool Cloud is there a way i can contact you please?

Comment: @RM2020 Nope, I dont think its safe to give off personal info off site, sorry.

Comment: @CoolCloud, I agree with you about that, but i'm looking for an advice from someone expert like you. I sent you a text on your page, i guess you didn't see it.
if there is any way you feel its safe for you to communicate please let me know.
Thanks,

Comment: sorry for that, i can't send here a message because i don't have 20 repetition.
I'm new here, I sent you an email to your gmail via NihaalNZ website.
again, I completely respect your privacy, I'm looking to learn here. Thank you.